# How to get / set value of a float2 field in a custom editor script?

Tags: unity, editors

I wrote this code:

```
var waveOrig = element.FindPropertyRelative("origin");
waveOrig.vector2Value = EditorGUI.Vector2Field(dirRect, "Point of Origin", waveOrig.vector2Value);
```

However, Unity logs errors because of this piece of code:

> Mismatched types in SetValue
> UnityEditor.SerializedProperty:set_vector2Value (UnityEngine.Vector2)

> Mismatched types in GetValue - return value is junk
> UnityEditor.SerializedProperty:get_vector2Value ()

Not sure how should I fix this, any help?

PS. "origin" element is a `float2` type

Comment: Are you aware that [`Vector2`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2.html) from the Unity core API and [`float2`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.mathematics@1.2/api/Unity.Mathematics.float2.html) from the Mathematics package are not the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to allow a user to modify the value, you can use the generic `PropertyField()` to automatically use the editor's default representation for whatever field type it happens to be:

```
EditorGUI.PropertyField(dirRect, waveOrigin, new GUIContent("Point of Origin"));
```

But if you want to extract the value they set and read / modify it, then it would be useful to give yourself a couple helper methods:

```
public static class SerializedPropertyExtensions {
    public static Vector2 GetFloat2AsVector(this SerializedProperty property) {
        Vector2 output;
        var p = property.Copy();
        p.Next(true);
        output.x = p.floatValue;
        p.Next(true);
        output.y = p.floatValue;
        return output;
    }

    public static void SetFloat2FromVector(this SerializedProperty property, Vector2 value) {        
        var p = property.Copy();
        p.Next(true);
        p.floatValue = value.x;
        p.Next(true);
        p.floatValue = value.y;        
    }
}
```

Then you can work with the `Vector2Field` as you were trying to do:

```
var v = waveOrigin.GetFloat2AsVector();
v = EditorGUI.Vector2Field(dirRect, "Point of Origin", v);
waveOrigin.SetFloat2FromVector(v);
```

Don't forget to call `serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties()` to commit the changes the user's made to the object's data.